# How to remove footer section perfectly in genesis?

Tags: wordpress, hook, genesis

I tried to remove footer section on kreativ theme in genesis.

```
enter code hereremove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
```

but I can see footer section with black background.
please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_close', 15 );
```

it worked for me perfectly.